# Alternative book to do Carmo Differential forms and Applications

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

This book is a good text connecting differential forms and the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (which match my project topic). But this book is too compact for me to self-study. Is there any alternative to this book, which, in the same way, introduce differential forms and then prove the Stoke's theorem and the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem using Cartan structural equations from differential forms?

Comment: @TedShifrin
I have finished O'Neill. But from what I know, O'Neill explains only the special case of differential forms for surfaces (mostly about 1-form and 2-form). do Carmo introduces the differential forms in a more general sense, for example, he proves stokes theorem for $(n-1)$ forms, but O'Neill proves only for 1 form. After I finished O'Neill, I wished to proceed further on differential geometry and I found this book on differential forms by Carmo. I am telling the truth. Maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't ready to read some graduate texts in differential geometry (of which there are plenty, but it's hard to find texts that do things just with differential forms), I recommend this book by Jeanne Clelland

https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-178/.

You haven't told us your background in analysis, topology, etc.

For lectures by a master, see Chern/Chen/Lam's book:

https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3812

Comment: I have finished the standard point set topology course and also real,complex and intro to functional analysis.

Comment: Yes, so Clelland's book is sophisticated but still focusing on surfaces. You should probably start learning about manifolds in general. I'm assuming you have a strong multivariable analysis background (much more important than anything you listed in analysis). There are lots of new books, but I'm somewhat fond of Spivak (but 5 volumes and wordy) and Boothby (to get started on manifolds and Riemannian geometry).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I will certainly look up for these books